# How To Reset File input using livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

does anybody knows how to reset my input type="file". I'm been using the `$this->reset()` to clear the property of the input `type="file"`.

```php
    $this->reset(['type', 'name', 'institution', 'year', 'certification']);
```

[image]

Comment: how about just setting, `document.getElementById("uploadedfile").value = "";` in pure js script

Comment: okay thx for that, i'll try it

Comment: @bhucho is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: use jquery though syntax would just change working would be same, or use any frontend frameworks, why the above should work?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to use `id` for any other purposes you can render the input like this:

```
<input type="file" id="{{ rand() }}" >
```

Instead of using `rand()` you can also use some kind of counter or any other value that will change on every render. Different `id` will force livewire to completely replace the element with new one, thus empty. Just setting `value=""` won't help as `input type="file"` is immutable. This solution is taken from [here](https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/file-uploads-clear-the-input-field/1072/4)

Comment: Using `rand()` doesn't work for me. It clears the value as soon as I set one. Changing the ID as in the post you reference does work, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I found in **TALL Stack Tips** to remove filename from input field after uploading via Livewire.
https://talltips.novate.co.uk/livewire/livewire-file-uploads-using-s3#removing-filename-from-input-field-after-upload

> The solution involves implementing a counter to regulate the input file id

Answer (score 2):

To reset a file input in livewire I removed id from that input. And assign a null value to the value.

#### input without id

```
<label>Upload Image
    <input type="file" wire:model="image" class="w-full">
</label>
```

#### to assign null value

```
$this->image = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

input create two wire(wire:click and wire:model), It works.

**livewire**：

```
<input wire:click="fileClear('fileName')" wire:model="fileName"  type="file" id="fileName" name="fileName" >
```

**class**:

```
public function fileClear($inputId)
{
    $this->$inputId = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing @AlexYokisama answer

Yes the easy way is using `id` as the following.

```
<input type="file" id="{{ $rand }}" >
```

And then in you `livewire` component you need to declare this `public $rand`

And you can use it safely in your reset function.

```
public $rand;

public function resetForm()
    {
        $this->rand++;
    }
```