# Buggy livewire loop on input date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a looped input date in my livewire component, the loop works but every other request that I make to change the `$term` the loop runs again but shows 1 less  input date.

My term model, I have a fake button to help the user remove focus on the input thus making the request to change the value.

```
<input class="form-control @error('term') is-invalid @enderror " id="term" type="number" name="term" wire:model.lazy="term" min='0' step='1'>
```

This is the loop.

```
@for ($i; $i <= $term-1; $i++) 
       <div class="form-group row ">
       <label for="date" class="col-md-3 col-form-label "><small>{{$i+1}}.</small> Date
       <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
       <div class="col-md-9">
          <input class="form-control @error('date') is-invalid @enderror" id="date" type="date" name="date" wire:model.defer="date.{{$i}}">
          @error('date') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
          @enderror
        </div>
        </div>
         @endfor
```

First request

[image: First request]

Second request

[image: Second Request]

If I try to make another request to change `$term` it will work for e.g I put `6` it will show 6 input dates but if I try to change again it will not render one input date.

Comment: Check this thread our, i dont see any problems in your code so this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834889/how-to-reset-file-input-using-livewire

Answer (score 0):

create a nested component for that.

nested-date-input

```
<div>
 <div class="form-group row ">
   <label for="date" class="col-md-3 col-form-label "><small>{{$i+1}}.</small> Date
     <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
       <div class="col-md-9">
         <input class="form-control @error('date') is-invalid @enderror" id="date" type="date" name="date" wire:model.defer="date.{{$i}}">
         @error('date') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
          @enderror
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

in the parent blade

```
@for ($i; $i <= $term-1; $i++) 
  @livewire('nested-date-input',['id' => $id],key($id.'input-date'))
@endfor
```

otherwise you can work around using the wire:key directive in the parent div element or the element itself

```
<div class="col-md-9" wire:key="{{ $id }}-input-date">
  <input class="form-control @error('date') is-invalid @enderror" id="date" type="date" name="date" wire:model.defer="date.{{$i}}">
     @error('date') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>@enderror
</div>
```

Personally I prefer the nested component solution.